# objective-c managing order for subviews

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiview, subviews

I have a UIView with several UIImages (subviews) that holds photos that the user choose from the photo library. I want to support a feature where the user can rearrange the order of the subviews. The user gets a modalviewcontroller, where he can drag and drop the views in order and place it in place. But when I want to update the order of the subviews nothing happens. The only thing that succeeds is placing the object I drag to the top using bringSubviewToFront:, but that's not what I want.

The method I want to use is `exchangeSubviewAtIndex:i withSubviewAtIndex:index`. But I can't get it to work. Do you guys have any suggestions of how I should tackle this?

Thanks in advance!
Michael

Comment: How are you implementing the `exchangeSubview...` method at the moment?

Comment: I think seeing some code would be helpful here. How are you placing the subviews in their parent view to begin with? That is, are the UIImageView's laid out so they are all visible within the UIView? Do they overlap in some way? Are you trying to present something like a stack of photos?

Comment: I don't know if echangeSubviewAtIndex:... explicitly calls [view setNeedsDisplay], or [view setNeedsLayout]. you could try that, also make sure your indices are valid and in the range of (0- [[view subviews]count]-1).

Comment: Its an app where you have a stack of images (overlapped) that you can watch a sequence of.

I use ELCImagePicker, an extension of the camera roll, which allows us to select multiple images in the camera roll.

I get the returned images in a dictionary like so:

    for(NSDictionary *dict in info) {
      UIImageView *thisImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[dict objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]];
      [array insertObject:thisImageView atIndex:[thearray count]];
      [thisImageView release];
 }

Comment: I then push a view controller which shows me the right images – it shows my UIView subclass, SpinnerView

Inside SpinnerView, i lay out the subviews:

    spinnerImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:thearray];
    for (UIView *object in spinnerImages) {
     [object setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
     object.frame = self.frame;
     [self addSubview:object];
    }

Comment: When the user wants to manage the order, they click an "edit button" and get a modalViewController, an instance of the AQGridView library, which works like a tableViewController, but with some extensions. It works like a springboard app. When the user "drops" an image to a new place, I call
    // update the data store
        id obj = [[images objectAtIndex: _dragOriginIndex] retain];
     [images removeObjectAtIndex: _dragOriginIndex];
     [images insertObject: obj atIndex: index];
    [spinnerView exchangeSubviewAtIndex:_dragOriginIndex withSubviewAtIndex:index];

Answer (score 0):

You mention *"dropping an image in a new place"*, this implies you are moving the UIImageView in the (X,Y) co-ordinate system.  The index in the subviews array orders the views only in the Z direction (effecting which is "on top" if they overlap).  Swapping view order will **not** swap the (X,Y) coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Its an app where you have a stack of images (overlapped) that you can watch a sequence of.

I use ELCImagePicker, an extension of the camera roll, which allows us to select multiple images in the camera roll.

I get the returned images in a dictionary like so:

```
for(NSDictionary *dict in info) {
        UIImageView *thisImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[dict objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]];
        [array insertObject:thisImageView atIndex:[thearray count]];
        [thisImageView release];
}
```

I then push a view controller which shows me the right images – it shows my UIView subclass, SpinnerView

Inside SpinnerView, i lay out the subviews:

```
spinnerImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:thearray];
for (UIView *object in spinnerImages) {
    [object setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
    object.frame = self.frame;
    [self addSubview:object];
}
```

When the user wants to manage the order, they click an "edit button" and get a modalViewController, an instance of the AQGridView library, which works like a tableViewController, but with some extensions. It works like a springboard app. When the user "drops" an image to a new place, I call

```
[spinnerView exchangeSubviewAtIndex:_dragOriginIndex withSubviewAtIndex:index];
```

, just after the table have updated the array:

```
// update the data store
    id obj = [[images objectAtIndex: _dragOriginIndex] retain];
    [images removeObjectAtIndex: _dragOriginIndex];
    [images insertObject: obj atIndex: index];
```

Hope this helps to solve my puzzle a rid me of my headache :)